# Elementwise multiplication in Greta

Tags: r, greta

I'm writing a model in Greta and have run into a minor stumbling block: elementwise multiplication using Greta arrays.

**Reproducible error:**

```
library(greta)
library(MCMCpack)
```

The following works (no Greta arrays involved here):

```
pi <- rdirichlet(1, alpha = rep(1, 5))
tpi <- t(array(pi, dim = c(5, 10)))
tpi*2
```

The following does not work (Greta arrays involved here):

```
pi <- dirichlet(alpha = rep(1, 5), dim = 1)
tpi <- t(array(pi, dim = c(5, 10)))
tpi*2
Error in tpi * 2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

The following also works (although pi is not an array whereas tpi is):

```
2*pi
```

But I need to perform the array expansion operation (step 2) in my model.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [open issue](https://github.com/greta-dev/greta/issues/214) with reshaping arrays in Greta. This should be resolved in the next releases but in the meantime here is an alternative proposed by Greta developer @goldingn (see [comments here](https://github.com/greta-dev/greta/issues/123#issuecomment-412711587)):

Instead of:

```
tpi <- t(array(pi, dim = c(5, 10)))
```

Use:

```
tpi <- do.call(rbind, replicate(10, pi))
```

The elementwise multiplication that follows will no longer yield an error.